# Разбор программы.Не совсем понятно

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace Leaning1
{
  class Program
  {
    static int method(params int[] a)
    { 
        int min = a[0];
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if ( a[i] < min )
            {
                min = a[i];

            }

        }
        Console.Write(min);
        return min;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int min = 0;
        min = method(4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 7);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос.

Comment: @Igor, не совсем понятен комментарий.

Comment: странно...вроде все понятно